# How to get the totalTime in java?

Tags: java, time

I have read a lot of answers here regarding getting the totalTime. I tried to apply this code that I found to my code:

```
long secs = (dateFormatter.format(now2) - dateFormatter.format(now1)) / 1000;
int hours = secs / 3600;
secs = secs % 3600;
int mins = secs / 60;
secs = secs % 60;
```

My code:

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
 {
 LogicalChecker lc = new LogicalChecker();
 Date now1 = new Date();
 Date now2 = new Date();
 cobadatabase cb = new cobadatabase(studNumTF.getText());
 String output;

  if(e.getActionCommand() == "Log In")
    {
        if(station == 0)
        {
            lc.StationCheck(0);
        }
        else if(seatOccupied[station-1] == true)
        {
            lc.StationCheck(2);
        }
        else if(!studNumTF.getText().equals(cb.getStudentNumber()))
        {
             studNumTF.setText("");
             lc.StationCheck(3); 
        }
        else
        {
            seatOccupied[station-1] = true;


                Aid[station-1].setText(cb.getStudentNumber());
                Afirstname[station-1].setText(cb.getFirstName());
                Alastname[station-1].setText(cb.getLastName());  
                seat[station-1].setBackground(Color.red);
                Atime[station-1].setText(dateFormatter.format(now1));
                occupiedSeatCounter++;


        }
    }

  if(e.getActionCommand() == "Log Out")
    {
        if(station == 0)
        {
            lc.StationCheck(0);
        }
        else if(Aid[station-1].getText() == "Vacant Station")
        {
            lc.StationCheck(1);
        }
        else
        {

            Aid[station-1].setText("Vacant Station");
            Afirstname[station-1].setText("---------");
            Alastname[station-1].setText("---------");
            seat[station-1].setBackground(Color.green);
            Atime[station-1].setText("00:00:00");
            seatOccupied[station-1] = false;
            studNumTF.setText("");
            output = "Time Check-Out "+dateFormatter.format(now2)+"\n Total Time: ";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,output, "Check-Out.",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        }
}

}
```

But it gives an error that says operator cannot be applied to java.lang.String. I do not know what to do to get its total time and display it to the JOptionPane that I have created. I really need help.

Comment: [`DateFormat#format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format(java.util.Date)) returns a `String`, not an integer as your first code attempts to do.

Comment: So in that case, Can it still be possible to get its total time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is here: `dateFormatter.format(now2) - dateFormatter.format(now1)` because like @Luiggi said the format returns a string. You should do something like: `now2.getTime() - now1.getTime()` to get the difference in milliseconds.

Comment: @Luiggi Thanks, I was assuming that he will replace the code and the division will be still in place.

Comment: Also change `if(e.getActionCommand() == "Log Out")` to `if("Log Out".equals(e.getActionCommand()))`.

Comment: If diff is the difference in milliseconds from above, long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;  
long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60; long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 60;

Comment: @saya these kind of Date and Time operations would be easier to code (and understand) if you use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).